# VRC task 3: file name error

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Error [SystemPaths.cc:355] File or path does not exist["fire_hose_long/meshes/coupling.stl"]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1709/vrc-task-3:-file-name-error/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Which branch are you using? Works for me.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0